# Installation of Torch not working

Tags: lua, torch, luarocks

I have installed Torch by following the instructions [here](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_), which comes with Lua 5.1, but Lua 5.3 was installed previously on my system. Now when I try to run a program using Torch, I get the following error messages:

```
/Users/Marcel/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: module 'Settings.arguments' not found:No LuaRocks module found for Settings.arguments
    no field package.preload['Settings.arguments']

no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/Settings/arguments.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/Settings/arguments/init.lua'
```

It would seem as if Torch is looking for its own version of Lua in the system directories, which only contain the previously installed version. Is there any way to fix this, or must I uninstall the Lua 5.3?

Thanks!

Comment: With Torch and Linux, it is sometimes black magic. Try 1) reinstall Torch, 2) If you are working from behind a gateway, you need to set up the proxy details by passing a `export {http,https,ftp}_proxy='http://<USERNAME>:<PASS>@<gateway_IP>:<port>'` command, *but* make sure all non-digits and non-letters in your username and password are percent encoded. Well, `.` can be used as is, but I had `;` in my password, and had to replace it with `%3B`. You may use [this tool to convert chars](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Answer (score -1):

Simply change `TORCH_LUA_VERSION` value to `LUAXX`, as it is explain in installation instructions with 5.2 version. For 5.3 version, use `LUA53`:

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch

# clean old torch installation
./clean.sh
# optional clean command (for older torch versions)
# curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/ezinstall/master/clean-old.sh | bash

# https://github.com/torch/distro : set env to use lua
TORCH_LUA_VERSION=LUA53 ./install.sh
```